# Spring MVC and Gradle (multimodules): how refer the /WEB-INF/ content how a dependency for a module for Testing

Tags: spring-mvc, gradle, build.gradle, thymeleaf

I am working with:

- Spring Framework - 5.0.4.RELEASE
- Gradle - 4.7
- Thymeleaf - 3.0.9.RELEASE

All the project is based with multi modules.

About `Spring Framework` and `Thymeleaf` integration I have the following

```
@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/html/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    //templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
    return templateEngine;
}

//In other class

@Bean
public ViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver(SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine) {
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(springTemplateEngine);
    return viewResolver;
}
```

Among many modules I have these two:

- `thymeleaf-02-controller`: all about the `@Controller`s
- `thymeleaf-02-web`: all about the `.html` files (css, js too)

Yes, is important have separated all about the `.java` files from all about the web files (`.html`, `.js` etc ...)

About the `Gradle` their configurations:

In the `thymeleaf-02-web` module exists:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

project(':thymeleaf-02-web') {

    description 'Web (HTML, JS, CSS)'

    dependencies {

        exportedProjects.each{
            if("$it"!=":thymeleaf-02-web")
                compile project("$it")
        }

    }

    webAppDirName = 'src/main/webapp'

    war {
        version=''
        baseName = warBaseName
    }

    ...

}
```

In the `thymeleaf-02-controller` module exists:

```
project(':thymeleaf-02-controller') {

    description 'Web - Controller'

    dependencies {

       compile project(':thymeleaf-02-infrastructure')
       compile project(':thymeleaf-02-service-api')

       ...      

       //Omicron: 
       //What is the correct approach?
       //The code shown below does not work
       testCompile project(':thymeleaf-02-web')
       testRuntime project(':thymeleaf-02-web')       
       testRuntime fileTree(dir: "/WEB-INF/view/html", include: '*.html')

    }

}
```

**Note:** If the multi module project is exported to a `.war` file all work fine, it of course in `Tomcat`. Thus the `runtime` environment is stable

The **problem** is about the `testing` environment, it just for the `thymeleaf-02-controller` module. Thus always appears:

```
[main] ERROR org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - 
[THYMELEAF][main] Exception processing template "persona/deleteOne": 
An error happened during template parsing 
(template: "ServletContext resource 
[/WEB-INF/view/html/persona/deleteOne.html]") 
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: 
An error happened during template parsing 
(template: "ServletContext resource 
[/WEB-INF/view/html/persona/deleteOne.html]")

...

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not open ServletContext resource 
[/WEB-INF/view/html/persona/deleteOne.html]

...
```

The error is clear, thanks to `FileNotFoundException`

I already have done the following 'solution':

- [Thymeleaf : org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885884/thymeleaf-org-thymeleaf-exceptions-templateinputexception)

But nothing, the problem remains.

What is the correct approach to resolve the `Omicron` section shown above?.

Therefore only for *testing* the `thymeleaf-02-controller` module is not able to refer/reach/see/use all the `.html` files located in the `/WEB-INF/view/html/..` directory from the `thymeleaf-02-web` module.

One thing that is curious is that must exists at least one `.java` file in the `src/main/java` *Source Folder* in the `thymeleaf-02-web` module to see in the `thymeleaf-02-controller` module the `thymeleaf-02-web` how a dependency through the `Project and External Dependencies`. Otherwise `thymeleaf-02-web` does not appear how a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is apply the following logic

```
@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/html/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    return templateResolver;
}
```

Thus:

- From `templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/html/");`
- To `templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/html/");`